# How to add a new language to Plone

Tags: plone

We need a way to classify pages or files as being of a language not already known in the standard language list in Plone/Zope. We don't need any translation or other functionality, just a way classify items as these new languages. 
What is the best practice way of handling this?
We are currently looking at using ATVocabularyManager to import a new list of languages and then creating a plugin that uses schemaextender to adjust the vocabulary used by the DC metadata language field on all Plone content. Is there a more out of the box way of doing this?

Some of the languages we want to add don't have standard language codes such as Koori, Assyrian, Soranî, Tetum, Dari and Karen. 
We also have a similar but related need to display Chinese Traditional and Chinese Simplified using these names, rather than as Chinese China and Chinese HongKong.

Comment: Which language is it, that you want to add?

Comment: I've added the languages above

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Add new language in Plone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944285/add-new-language-in-plone) , the best way is to contact the i18n-team for adding a new language, even if you don't have translation-strings, yet. They can be contributed step-by-step and in case also be overwritten for individual purposes.

Comment: These are non standard languages, which don't have official language codes so it's not appropriate to have them added to the Plone core

Comment: 'Karen' f.e. does have a code, I don't know by heart which ISO-convention exactly Plone is following (i18n-team should know), but it still seems to me the proper way to go. If there really is no lang-code, I'd try it to be added to an ISO.