# Add new language in Plone

Tags: plone

How to add new language in Plone 4.2? I looked at the code on plone.i18n.locales.languages.py. The languages is hard coded inside the code. Anyway we can extend the language list without modified the core code. Any plug in, may be? Thanks.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Which language is it, you want to add?

Comment: I'm also asking, because you might have the same langs as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944181/how-to-add-a-new-langage-to-plone and you could 'unleash some synergies' instead of each brewing a private solution.

Answer (score 1):

Benefit from the advantages of opensource and contribute it right to the core.

The i18n-team will be happy to help you further, just leave a post in the forum:

http://plone.org/support/forums/i18n

Comment: The process would be creating a work of plone.i18n.locales on Github, directly patch the code with your language stuff and then run this modified add-on locally, then push changes to upstream

Comment: Here please see http://plone.org/documentation/kb/installing-add-ons-quick-how-to Downloading and configuring add-on package from github